# Creating POCO classes that are compatible with NHibernate and EF 4.1

Tags: nhibernate, data-modeling, poco, entity-framework-4.1

I know that all members of a POCO class for NHibernate must be defined as virtual, and in EF (code first), you only need to set the collection / reference objects as virtual for lazy loading.

So if I want to create POCO objects that are compatible with both EF and NH should I just declare every member of my POCO classes as virtual??

The reason for wanting this is that we're currently evaluating both EF and NHibernate ORM's and if we end up changing our plans down the road, we don't want to have to update our POCO's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you're not forced to declare every property as virtual in NH. If you turn-off the lazy load behaviour ('on' by default) you no longer need to declare all those "virtuals", and may specify case-by-case which properties are lazy-loaded.

So, if you want, you may have a POCO with just reference objects as virtual in both NH and EF.

Sidenote: Anyway, and just for the effort of it, I would declare all properties as virtual and be done with it :)

Comment: (1) Does NH only require virtual properties for lazy loading? I thought it created an inheritance based proxy (unless an interface was provided) and therefore required virtual props and methods. (2) If you'd turn of lazy loading, you'd loose many of the benfits an ORM gives you.

Comment: I agree with your sidenote: make them virtual.

Comment: If you mark the class to not be lazy loaded, it should no longer create a proxy. Like <class name="Foo" table="Foo" lazy="false" >, hence not requiring virtual

Comment: Anyway, I'm just being pedantic. I do not recommend this, and I agree with you when you say that you would loose many of the benefits of NHibernate :)

Answer (score 3):

EF needs virtual navigation properties for lazy loading but it also uses `virtual` scalar/complex properties for dynamic change tracking so if you mark all properties as `virtual` it will be correct approach.

Anyway do you evaluation upfront. `virtual` properties will be minimal issue if you decide to change ORM later - you will find much harder problems.

Answer (score 1):

Or alternatively, if you create an interface or abstract base for your POCO's, you can use the `<class name="MyPoco" proxy="IMyPoco"/>` attribute in NHibernate which also eliminates the need for virtual properties, since NH then defers to creating its subclasses from the proxy rather than from your POCO directly.

Comment: very interesting. All of my POCO's do derive from an abstract class - I didn't know this was possible.